# Sum of one column group by date column

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

This should be simple enough but something's gotten me big time.

All I have is a table with just TWO columns, something like:

``````````````````````````````
 WordCount          DateAdded
 `````````````````````````````
 96                 2008-11-07 09:16:31.810
 32                 2008-11-07 15:26:27.547
 25                 2008-11-23 16:05:39.640
 62                 2008-12-03 12:33:03.110
``````````````````````````````

and so on.

I want to calculate the **total word count for each day** - I group them by dateadded and select sum of WordCount and finally get the syntax error (wordcount has to be in group by clause) but now I am getting nulls for day's count

This is my query:

```
select SUM(WordCount) as 'words per day' from @WordsCount group by DateAdded, WordCount
```

this is selecting just null. How can I know what is wrong?

thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What if you use:

```
select SUM(WordCount) as 'words per day' 
from @WordsCount 
group by DateAdded
```

I don't see why you're also grouping by the word count....

Also, since the `DateAdded` likely is a `DATETIME` column including a time portion, you might want to group by just the date:

```
select SUM(WordCount) as 'words per day' 
from @WordsCount 
group by CAST(DateAdded AS DATE)
```

**Update:** if I try this, the query works just fine ....

```
DECLARE @WordsCnt TABLE (WordCount INT, DateAdded DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @wordsCnt(WordCount, DateAdded)
VALUES(96, '2008-11-07 09:16:31.810'),
      (32, '2008-11-07 15:26:27.547'),
      (25, '2008-11-23 16:05:39.640'),
      (62, '2008-12-03 12:33:03.110')

select CAST(DateAdded AS DATE), SUM(WordCount) as 'words per day' 
from @WordsCnt
group by CAST(DateAdded AS DATE)
```

and produces the output:

```
2008-11-07   128
2008-11-23    25
2008-12-03    62
```

Comment: tsql is complaining that select clause cannot have ``WordCount`` as it's not contained in the group by clause

Comment: Oh, I just realized I am just selecting ``WordsCnt`` instead of ``SUM(wordscnt)``.. Added sum and it works!! thanks!

Comment: wonder why it complains when ``sum`` isn't included? first I tried to select all rows, and then adding sum, so whne i tried without sum it gave error, so I had to add it to group by clause..

Comment: @LocustHorde: well if you have the `WordCount` **without** the `SUM(...)` in there - then **OF COURSE** it will complain! That's the whole point of a GROUP BY - either your column must be in the GROUP BY clause, or it must be aggregated by a SUM(), MIN(), MAX(), AVG() function......

Comment: You still helped me, since I am still learning a lot, this was very usefull!

Answer (score 7):

I think this should give you word count per day

```
select      SUM(WordCount) as 'words per day' , cast(DateAdded as date) dateAdded
from        WordsCount 
group by    cast(DateAdded as date)
```

Comment: Thank you, I realized the error was that I had included word count in group by clause too!