# How to improve query speed in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

I'm trying to optimize my query speed as much as possible. A side problem is that I cannot see the exact query speed, because it is rounded to a whole second. The query does get the expected result and takes about 1 second. The final query should be extended even more and for this reason i am trying to improve it. How can this query be improved?

The database is constructed as an electricity utility company. The query should eventually calculate an invoice. I basically have 4 tables, APX price, powerdeals, powerload, eans_power.

APX price is an hourly price, powerload is a quarterly hour volume. First step is joining these two together for each quarter of an hour.

Second step is that I currently select the EAN that is indicated in the table eans_power.

Finally I will join the Powerdeals that currently consist only of a single line and indicates from which hour, until which hour and weekday from/until it should be applicable. It consist of an hourly volume and price. Currently it is only joined on the hours, but it will be extended to weekdays as well.

> MYSQL Query:

```
SELECT l.DATE, l.PERIOD_FROM, a.PRICE, l.POWERLOAD, 
SUM(a.PRICE*l.POWERLOAD), SUM(d.hourly_volume/4) 
FROM timeseries.powerload l 
INNER JOIN timeseries.apxprice a ON l.DATE = a.DATE 
INNER JOIN contracts.eans_power c ON  l.ean = c.ean 
LEFT OUTER JOIN timeseries.powerdeals d ON d.period_from <= l.period_from 
AND d.period_until >= l.period_until 
WHERE l.PERIOD_FROM >= a.PERIOD_FROM 
AND l.PERIOD_FROM < a.PERIOD_UNTIL 
AND l.DATE >= '2018-01-01' 
AND l.DATE <= '2018-12-31' 
GROUP BY l.date
```

> Explain:

```
1   SIMPLE  c   NULL    system  PRIMARY,ean NULL    NULL    NULL    1   100.00  Using temporary; Using filesort 

1   SIMPLE  l   NULL    ref EAN EAN 21  const   35481   11.11   Using index condition

1   SIMPLE  d   NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   100.00  Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)

1   SIMPLE  a   NULL    ref DATE    DATE    4   timeseries.l.date   24  11.11   Using index condition
```

> Create table queries:

apxprice

```
CREATE TABLE `apxprice` (
  `apx_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `period_from` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `period_until` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`apx_id`),
  KEY `DATE` (`date`,`period_from`,`period_until`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=29664 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

powerdeals

```
CREATE TABLE `powerdeals` (
  `deal_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_deal` date NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL,
  `weekday_from` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `weekday_until` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `period_from` time NOT NULL,
  `period_until` time NOT NULL,
  `hourly_volume` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type_deal_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `contract_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`deal_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

powerload

```
CREATE TABLE `powerload` (
  `powerload_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ean` varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `period_from` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `period_until` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `powerload` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`powerload_id`),
  KEY `EAN` (`ean`,`date`,`period_from`,`period_until`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=61039 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

eans_power

```
CREATE TABLE `eans_power` (
  `ean` char(19) NOT NULL,
  `contract_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoicing_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `affix` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `postal` char(6) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ean`),
  KEY `ean` (`ean`,`contract_id`,`invoicing_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

> Sample data tables

apx_prices

- apx_id,date,period_from,period_until,price
- 1,2016-01-01,00:00:00,01:00:00,23.86
- 2,2016-01-01,01:00:00,02:00:00,22.39

powerdeals

- deal_id,date_deal,start_date,end_date,weekday_from,weekday_until,period_from,period_until,hourly_volume,price,type_deal_id,contract_id
- 1,2019-05-15,2018-01-01,2018-12-31,1,5,08:00:00,20:00:00,1000,50,3,1

powerload

- powerload_id,ean,date,period_from,period_until,powerload
- 1,871688520000xxxxxx,2018-01-01,00:00:00,00:15:00,9
- 2,871688520000xxxxxx,2018-01-01,00:15:00,00:30:00,11

eans_power

- ean,contract_id,invoicing_id,street,number,affix,postal,city
- 871688520000xxxxxx,1,1,road,14,postal,city

> Result, without sum() and group by:

- DATE,PERIOD_FROM,PRICE,POWERLOAD,a.PRICE*l.POWERLOAD,d.hourly_volume/4,
- 2018-01-01,00:00:00,27.20,9,244.80,NULL
- 2018-01-01,00:15:00,27.20,11,299.20,NULL

> Result, with sum() and group by:

- DATE, PERIOD_FROM, PRICE, POWERLOAD, SUM(a.PRICE*l.POWERLOAD), SUM(d.hourly_volume/4)
- 2018-01-01,08:00:00,26.33,21,46193.84,12250.0000
- 2018-01-02, 08:00:00,47.95,43,90623.98,12250.0000

Comment: *"The query does get the expected result and takes about 1 second. Can this query be improved?"* I very much doubt it returns the correct results (if it does it's pure luck) as that is not how you should use [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: As your query is basically wrong i would suggest [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results..

Comment: One suggestion is to store date and time as a single entity

Comment: Before starting to optimize, please fix the `GROUP BY`.  Notice that the `SELECT` is fetching columns (eg, price) that (apparently) depend on the hour.

Comment: There seems to be 1 contract.  Will there be multiple contracts?  Will they end on specific days?  What about changing mid-day?  Also what about switching to/from daylight-savings-time?

Comment: Is "hourly volume" an amount consumed?  Or an amount allotted?

Comment: One of the ON clauses checks for one time range being contained in another.  What if, instead, they are _overlapping_?

Comment: @Strawberry, from what I read on the internet this would actually slow down, see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188667/best-database-and-table-design-for-billions-of-rows-of-data

Comment: @RickJames and @ Raymond, I will look at the group by, thank you. I used them to sum them by the day.

Comment: @RickJames, it is the amounnt consumed.

Comment: The respondent there has specific reasons for adopting that approach (that I'm not entirely convinced by) that, don't necessarily apply here.

Comment: @RickJames, There will be more than one contract. There is actually a contract table that will tell when the contract starts and ends. They will end on specific days,  generally at the end of the year, never mid day. Gas however, will end also at a specific hour. Daylight savings I tackled by have some days with 25 hours, or 23 hours.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, Currently looking into the group by. I wanted to sum the results by date. And later make a query for grouping by months. I got it from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160315/sum-of-one-column-group-by-date-column) , so how would you propose to tackle this problem?

Comment: the expected results based on the example data are still missing?

Comment: @RaymondNijland, just added the result

Answer (score 2):

Preliminary optimizations:

- Use InnoDB, not MyISAM.
- Use `CHAR` only for constant-lenght strings
- Use consistent datatypes (see `ean`, for example)

For an alternative to using time-to-the-second, check out the [*Handler counts*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts) .

Because range tests (such as `l.PERIOD_FROM >= a.PERIOD_FROM AND l.PERIOD_FROM < a.PERIOD_UNTIL`) are essentially impossible to optimize, I recommend you expand the table to have one entry per hour (or 1 per quarter hour, if necessary).  Looking up a row via a key is *much faster* than doing a scan of "ALL" the table.  9K rows for an entire year is trivial.

When you get past these recommendations (and the Comments), I will have more tips on optimizing the indexes, especially InnoDB's `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at InnoDB.
Thanks, I will start using more CHAR for fixed length strings and consistant data types. I will look into the handler counts.

Comment: The problem is that every deal is unique and may have a different start/end hour/date and may only applicable for a certain weekday. If I would apply this rule, than one deal would essentially take for example 365 days * 48 timeslot, I am not sure if this is the way to go.

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: @Introductiontoprogramming - A 1-day deal may need a different query than a 1-year deal.  I would expect to need to do some code in the application to help with the optimization.  (Or use a messy Stored Procedure.)  My gut says (from years of experience) that you have a rather complex problem to optimize.

Comment: @Introductiontoprogramming - I'm interested in the concept, and predict that electrical utilities may someday us a granularity of a minute (not just 15m).  And it will be computed inside our self-driving electric cars as an optimization in recharging.  And our refrigerator, in deciding when to run the compressor.

Comment: just thinking out loud here. Most deals are in multiples of 1 month deals, on certain weekdays and hours. However, there is one type of deal "contract deal", which can be starting or ending mid month. I currently chose one table for all deals, in a format which will always be possible. However, I could also make two tables. One only containing month, year, weekdays and hours, and another like it is now. I think it would make things more complex.

Comment: Since the calculation will become more complex, I was also thinking about saving the results of the query in a separate table. This way I can have complex slow queries, but customer/company can view the results fast. I think this is the best way to go now.

Comment: The concept is indeed very interesting if you ask me. It is actually not some day, minute intervals is already happening for grid balancing.

Comment: @Introductiontoprogramming - Help me understand.  Does a deal last from some minute of one day to some minute of another day, possibly weeks later?  Or is a deal valid from, say, "noon to 4pm any day this month"?  Or maybe both types exist?  I ask because the `WHERE` clause is different for the two, and the optimization of them _may_ need separate tables or indexes or query formulation or who-knows-what.

Comment: The "noon to 4pm any day this month". I need to save the results in a seperate table anyway, because this is what is what will be invoiced.

Comment: Almost finished with this query. Now running into the problem / exercise in the case there are let's say a buy and a sell deal. However, with the left outer join I get all rows double, as in two times the powerload. I think I need to do a select sum group by nested there.